# Upload new build while old one at "Prepare for submission"

Tags: app-store-connect

A few months ago I uploaded a build (1.7.0) to iTunes Connect - I intended to do deploy it on Test Flight, but ended up using Hockey to test. So now I'm ready to try my first ever live release  (1.9.0).

1.7.0 is at "Prepare for submission" stage, and I cannot find a way to upload my current build:

[image]

Also, I accidentally created a tvOS entry, can I remove that?

Thanks!

EDit - I just found 1.9.0 in the TestFlight tab, having uploaded it from Xcode, using a Distribution profile:

```
Name:               Oct15 App Store
Type:               iOS Distribution
App ID:             xxxxx
Certificates:       1 total (which is an iOS Distribution cert)
Devices:            0 total
Enabled Services:   Game Center, In-App Purchase, Push Notifications
Expires:            Sep 24, 2016
```

Can I move that over to the review process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. My Apps > App Store > 1.7.0 Prepare for submission
2. Change `Version` 1.7.0 to 1.9.0 and Save

[image]

3. Upload your build (1.9.0)

I don't know how to remove tvOS entry, Sorry